# Unable to print text from file

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write a simple program that will print the contents of a text file one line at a time. However, whenever I run the program i just get a blank screen. I'm certain the file I am trying to read contains text over several lines. Any help as to why this isn't working would be super helpfull.

```
bool show() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("tasks.txt", ios::app);
    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        getline (myfile, line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since you only want to read the file, is there a reason why you're opening it in append mode?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you are using `ios::app` with `ifstream` (input stream), which makes no sense.

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/),

**ios::app:** All output operations are performed at the end of the file, appending the content to the current content of the file. `This flag can only be used in streams open for output-only operations.`

Try this:

```
std::string line;
ifstream myfile ("tasks.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check return value of `myfile.isopen()`?  Perhaps the file isn't there or you don't have read permission.

Oh yes, I missed that - the append flag.  Should be `ios::in`